# vba excel macro using too much memory (select.insert seems to be the cause)

Tags: excel, vba, memory, selection

I am struggling with a Macro that cannot get to the end because of too much memory usage.

I have a specific line that seems to be responsible for this:

Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

This is within a while loop and an if/else statement like this:

```
While SearchRow < lastRow

  If StrComp(...) = 0 Then
    ...
  End If 

  If StrComp(...) = 0 Then 
    ...
  End If

  If StrComp(...) = 0 _
  Or StrComp(...) = 0 _
  Or StrComp(...) = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(SearchRow, 1).EntireRow.Delete
  Else 
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(...).Cells(SearchRow, 1).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
  End If

Wend
```

I have runned the macro in debug lineby line and so when I get into the If/Or block then to the EndIf I see the memory usage in the task manager of windows jumping.

Do you have any explanation/suggestion on this ?

Many thanks for your help.
BR,
Massimo

Comment: can you provide more details? How much data are we talking about? what happens if you do this manually and not with code? We'll need to see more of the code as well. Whenever one talks about memory leakage, scrubbing too much out of the code will not help us debug. If you are worried about sheet/variable names, substitutions will work.

Comment: we are talking about 50k+ rows.
The issue was coming from columns shifting. I solved it as per below answer by adding needed columns upfront.

Comment: Excellent you got an answer. Make sure to mark it as the answer to your question. This will help others with similar situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I would even struggle with finding an elegant solution I would start off with optimizing the macro for refreshing formulas and the screen:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Please do not forget to turn them back to the original values when you are done with the sub.

This should prevent any recalculations during your insertion and prevent the screen from unnecessarily updating itself. This might actually solve your problem right away.

Now for an elegant solution we would need to see your whole code and see what you are struggling to achieve as most probably you are moving a lot of columns with data and formulas hence Excel has to process a lot in memory to move them to the right.

W/o seeing your code I would probably:

1. Think or rewriting it to prevent any Shift
2. Modify the code to do the insertions rather from the right to left than the other way round (to limit the number of columns needed to be moved)
3. Insert upfront many columns and hide them. Then in the code, when needed instead of inserting them you would unhide one of the hidden columns - most effective

Comment: Eventually, I went with the 3th option and added the needed columns upfront. That was a quick solution that solved my problem ! 
That's great ! Many thanks for your help !